# Adding Incrementing Citation ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've tried searching the issue and came up with nothing, so I'm looking for help.

What I'm trying to do is add incrementing IDs to individual citations by:

- Searching a Google Doc for a specific combination of characters that signal the end of the citation (checking to see if there are any in the document at all).
- If the characters are there, I'd like to find the first one, then place a '1' in between the two characters. Then the second one should have a '2' between it, the third should have a '3', and so on and so forth ensuring that all of the sets of characters have been replaced with unique number IDs

What is going wrong currently:

- Due to the elemental structure of the Google Doc, my script is replacing ALL instances within a paragraph with the same ID number, which can be 1 instance or it can be 20. When it moves to the next paragraph, every found instance of the character combination is getting the incremented ID.

I need a genius' help.

Here's the code base I've found that I've been struggling to modify:

```js
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var foundElement = body.findText("]]");
    
  
  var i = 1;
  
  
      while (foundElement != null) {
        // Get the text object from the element
        var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

        // Where in the Element is the found text?
        var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
        var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

        // Change the text
        
        foundText.replaceText("]]","]"+i+"]");
        
        // Find the next match
        foundElement = body.findText("]]", foundElement);
        i++
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

replaceText() will replace all the occurence in the element.

### Solution

To avoid this, you should use the start and end to delete and insert text.

Please see my code below. This worked on my end.

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var foundElement = body.findText("]]");
    
  
  var i = 1;
  
  
      while (foundElement != null) {
        // Get the text object from the element
        var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

        // Where in the Element is the found text?
        var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
        var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

        // Change the text
        
        foundText.deleteText(start, end)
        foundText.insertText(start, "]"+i+"]")     
           
        // Find the next match
        foundElement = body.findText("]]", foundElement);
        i++
    }
```

As you can see, I just modified the line where you replaceText() and transform it to a combination of deleteText() and insertText() methods.

Comment: Bam - you got it. Thank you so much! This change worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var foundElement = body.findText("]]");
  var i = 1;
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
    var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
    var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    foundText.replaceText("]]", "]" + i++ + "]");
    foundElement = body.findText("]]", end);//Modifed this and the end point of the last search.  And the i++ will use the i as it currently is and then increment it after the current operation.
  }
}
```

Each next search needs to start searching after the location of the preceeding element. [range element getEndOffsetInclusive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element#getEndOffsetInclusive())